# http error 403 issue in resuming download from google drive

Tags: download, drive, resume

i was downloading a file of about 400mb shared with me on google drive. I got an unstable internet connection and the file stopped at 94%. When i reconnect to internet and resumes the download, it does not resumes and says "http error 403: forbidden".

I searched the internet and it says to sign out of all the accounts and login to only one account. But i have only one account in my chrome, so that can't be the problem.

I reproduce the issue by intentionally pausing it at 5% and then resuming but got the same problem. 
It's very frustrating.
I have tried downloading with chrome as well as FDM(Free Download Manager) but nothing works.

If anyone knows about this please tell me how to solve it.

P.S: Well I have successfully downloaded it again but still it is very annoying because i have lots of file to download which are almost the same size and this error is coming on all files which are paused and then resumed.

Please HELP!!